# how to run for loop to check for new pattern in string

Tags: python, regex

I want to run for loop to generate new regex for checking in the file for example

```
import re
K = "MS-85409/LN-85409/L-1"
le = ["L-1","L-11","L-112"]
for i in le:
    s="[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/"+i+"$"
    x = re.search(r's,K)
    if x:
        do something
    else:
        pass
```

where i want to do is,

on first loop of for `s` be `"[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/"+L-1$"` and put that in `x=re.search(r'[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/"+L-1$',K)`
and search it in `K` if matches do something and then second loop `s` will be
`"[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/"+L-11$"` and put that in `x=re.search(r'[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/"+L-11$',K)`
and search it in `K` if matches do something and so on..

Comment: the problem is I can't pass s into the string which is 's' in this case and If I am passing it like re.search(r " ' "+s,K) it says r is not defined. and If I am passing it like re.search(r'[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/"+L-1$',K) it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change those 2 lines:

```
s="[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/"+i+"$"
x = re.search(r's,K)
```

into:

```
s=r"[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/"+i+"$"
x = re.search(s,K)
```